# How fast can I read Arduino port D?

Tags: port-mapping

I'm trying to see how fast I can read an Arduino IO port.  It's being toggled with an random speed /white square wave and I want to see which is faster, the Arduino or the signal.  The pin on port D is driven by an open collector comparator (LM311).

So I have this code

```
buffer[0] = PORTD;
buffer[1] = PORTD;
buffer[2] = PORTD;
buffer[3] = PORTD;
buff...
```

...fer[28] = PORTD;
buffer[29] = PORTD;

that I can read the port in burst mode.  This code is as fast as I can write I think.  I've unrolled a possible loop here.  buffer[] is a local variable as that seems faster.  I'm not an assembly expert so I can't really browse the assembly instructions.

I've added a 500 Ohm pullup resistor to the input pin that I'm interested in.  A lower value seems to give more randomly distributed values that a 10k resistor.

I tried timing buffer[0] ... buffer[29] readings and that returns 4 microseconds with interrupts off.  I hope that micros() doesn't need interrupts to function!  That would equate to 7.5 million readings /sec.  That's about 2 clock cycles per instruction on my 16 MHz board.  Can this be right?

How fast can this code run?

Comment: How did you time your unrolled code?

Comment: Turned interrupts off, recorded micros() before reading port 30 times, then print micros() - micros before.  Does that work?

Comment: I don't trust software, I always use a scope and a GPIO to get actual timing.

Answer (score 4):

Your timing seems reasonable.

At a rough guess, without actually compiling it, your code will turn into something along the lines of:

```
IN R24,PORTD  ;First read   - temp = PORTD     - 1 cycle
ST X+, R24    ;First store  - buffer[0] = temp - 2 cycle
IN R24,PORTD  ;Second read  - temp = PORTD     - 1 cycle
ST X+, R24    ;Second store - buffer[1] = temp - 2 cycle
...
```

This is indeed the fastest way of reading the port if you want to keep the data. Basically it will do an IO read from PORTD using the `IN` instruction which takes 1 clock cycle. Then it will perform a store to SRAM using the `STS` instruction which takes another 2 clock cycles. The store instruction can also post increment the pointer it is using (stored in the R28/R29 X-register pair in my example) for free which saves you time.

So basically that should do 3 clock cycles for every read - one to do the read, and one to do the store, or >5 million reads per second from a 16MHz clock.

---

There will additionally be a couple of cycles at the beginning to set X-register to point to the buffer. If the buffer is a constant pointer - i.e. the buffer has a fixed address, it will only take two instruction cycles at the beginning to load the address. If it is a non-constant address, it will take up to four as it has to load the address from the SRAM.

Comment: I'm surprised that a succession of buffer[const] = ... assembles to ST X+, I would have expected I'd need to use buffer[var++] = ... . I just ask as I'm going to want to do similar 'fast' things myself shortly

Comment: @Neil_UK GCC is quite clever when it wants to be. It will work out that each of the writes corresponds to a series of incrementing addresses and convert it into `ST X+` instructions. If you leave a gap, say miss buffer[10], it will probably keep the same optimisation but add an additional `ADIW X,1` in the gap rather than recalculating the address.

Comment: Yeh, I too was wondering about the array indexing.  I thought that it might take more processing.  One odd thing is that the readings change with the value of the pull up resistor.  With a higher value you get more "0" in the results for the same signal.  Probably one of those inductance things which  probably becomes apparent when reading at 8 MHz.  This is probably getting a bit fast for the general plug it in and hope Arduino style of design.  500 Ohms gives an evenish number of 1s and 0s.

Comment: `st X+, r24` takes two cycles, so that's 3 cycles for every read.

Comment: @EdgarBonet so it is. Only 1 cycle on ATTiny devices though :). I was using [this](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-0856-AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual.pdf) but they have since updated it with a few corrections.

Comment: According to the [instruction set manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf#page=173), it's 2 cycles, except on XMEGA and on “reduced core” ATtinies. My understanding is that “reduced core” refers to the AVR core that lacks registers r0 through r15, i.e. the last line in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_instruction_set#Optional_feature_instructions). Most ATtinies, including the ones Arduino programmers are most likely to come across (e.g. ATtiny 85), are not “reduced core”.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried compiling your code with avr-gcc 4.9.2:

```c++
buffer[0]  = PORTD;
buffer[1]  = PORTD;
...
buffer[29] = PORTD;
```

Here is what I got:

```lisp
in  r24,    0x0b  ; temp = PORTD     – 1 cycle
sts 0x0110, r24   ; buffer[0] = temp – 2 cycles
in  r24,    0x0b  ; temp = PORTD     – 1 cycle
sts 0x0111, r24   ; buffer[1] = temp – 2 cycles
...
```

That's 3 cycles per read, i.e. a 5.33 Mhz reading frequency. For
some reason the compiler didn't want to use the `st X+, r24`
instruction suggested in Tom Carpenter's answer. Let's try to hint the
compiler a little bit, and rewrite the C code as follows:

```c++
uint8_t * p = buffer;
*p++ = PORTD;
*p++ = PORTD;
...
```

This generated the exact same assembly! The compiler somehow figured out
the address of each memory write, and it replaced each occurrence of the
pointer `p` by an explicit address. To prevent this kind of
“optimization”, let's make the pointer a variable whose value is unknown
at compile time:

```c++
void fill_buffer(uint8_t *p)
{
    *p++ = PORTD;
    *p++ = PORTD;
    ...
    *p++ = PORTD;
}
```

Here is the generated assembly:

```lisp
movw r30,  r24   ; Z = p (Z is the register pair r31:r30)
in   r24,  0x0b  ; temp = PORTD   – 1 cycle
st   Z,    r24   ; *Z = temp      – 2 cycles
in   r24,  0x0b  ; temp = PORTD   – 1 cycle
std  Z+1,  r24   ; *(Z+1) = temp  – 2 cycles
...
in   r24,  0x0b  ; temp = PORTD   – 1 cycle
std  Z+29, r24   ; *(Z+29) = temp – 2 cycles
ret              ; return
```

Still 3 cycles per read. Here the compiler is using the `std`
(store with displacement) instruction rather than `st X+` (store with
post-increment).

In the end, what instruction the compiler chooses doesn't really matter.
All memory access instructions takes two cycles. Then, no matter what
you do, repeatedly transferring data from a port to RAM will take
3 cycles per transfer, irrespective of the instruction you choose
for the memory write.

Now, this doesn't mean you can't read faster. The AVR CPU core has
32 general purpose registers. Since you are only performing
30 port reads per burst, this means you can use the register file
as an ultra-fast temporary buffer. This seems easier to do in assembly,
and it will cost you a significant overhead in saving registers to the
stack and restoring them afterwards. But the read burst itself will be
faster:

```lisp
; declare as:
;   extern "C" void fill_buffer(uint8_t *p);
.global fill_buffer
fill_buffer:

    ; Prologue: save registers and move the pointer.
    push r2         ; save all the registers belonging to the caller:
    push r3         ;  - 18 register to save (r2 – r17, r28, r29)
    ...
    push r28        ;  - 2 cycles per register
    movw r30, r24   ; Z = p (Z = r31:r30 is a pointer register)

    ; Now we can read the port really fast.
    in   r0,  0x0b  ; temp_0  = PORTD – 1 cycle
    in   r1,  0x0b  ; temp_1  = PORTD – 1 cycle
    ...
    in   r29, 0x0b  ; temp_29 = PORTD – 1 cycle

    ; Now save to RAM.
    st   Z+,  r0    ; *Z++ = temp_0   – 2 cycles
    st   Z+,  r1    ; *Z++ = temp_1   – 2 cycles
    ...
    st   Z+,  r29   ; *Z++ = temp_29  – 2 cycles

    ; Epilogue: restore the registers.
    pop  r28        ; restore all the previously saved registers:
    ...
    pop  r3         ;  - 18 registes to restore 
    pop  r2         ;  - 2 cycles per register
    clr  r1         ; leave r1 cleared, as required by the ABI
    ret             ; return
```

Now we are reading the port at 16 MHz: one read per cycle!

It turns out that that we can convince the compiler to do exactly this.
I had to see to believe, but it works. Something essentially equivalent
to the above assembly can be generated from C++ like this:

```c++
// Quickly read the port into temporaries.
uint8_t temp_0  = PORTD;
uint8_t temp_1  = PORTD;
...
uint8_t temp_29 = PORTD;

// Now save to RAM.
buffer[0]  = temp_0;
buffer[1]  = temp_1;
...
buffer[29] = temp_29;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity what compiler optimisation flags were you using? Also when I tested it was with I believe avrgcc 4.6, so optimisation behaviour may have changed.

Comment: @TomCarpenter: I used `-Os`. And indeed, this may change between compiler versions.